# why isn't the following button switch case javascript working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ibm-mobilefirst

i am using the following code to get the value of button user click an dthen print the same in an label. i have made this code in Worklight project and when i run the project none of the other functions that i defined seems to work. but when i put this function in comments everything seems to work just fine.

i also tried working by directly putting the ids of the buttons directly to the switch case but that doesn't work either. i am new to the concept of javascript and unable to find a solution. necessary html is provided beneath the javascripts if that helps.

```
function typecheck(objButton) {
  exptype = document.getElementById("exptype");
  grocery = document.getElementById("button");
  medical = document.getElementById("button2");
  education = document.getElementById("button3");
  entertainment = document.getElementById("button4");
  automobile = document.getElementById("button5");
  insurance = document.getElementById("button6");
  others = document.getElementById("button7");
  switch (objButton)
case "grocery":
  exptype.innerHTML = "grocery";
  break;
case "medical":
  exptype.innerHTML = "medical";
  break;
case "education":
  exptype.innerHTML = "education";
  break;
case "entertainment":
  exptype.innerHTML = "entertainment";
  break;
case "automobile":
  exptype.innerHTML = "automobile";
  break;
case "insurance":
  exptype.innerHTML = "insurance";
  break;
default:
  exptype.innerHTML = "others";
  break;
}
```

html code :

```
<div data-role="collapsible" id="collapsible2">
  <h3>Category</h3>  
    <div data-role="controlgroup" id="controlgroup1">
      <a href="#" data-role="button" id="button" onclick="typecheck(this)">Grocery</a>
      <a href="#"   data-role="button" id="button2" onclick="typecheck(this)">Medical</a>
      <a href="#"   data-role="button" id="button3" onclick="typecheck(this)">Education</a>
      <a href="#"   data-role="button" id="button4" onclick="typecheck(this)">Entertainment</a>
      <a href="#"   data-role="button" id="button5" onclick="typecheck(this)">Automobile</a>
      <a href="#"   data-role="button" id="button6" onclick="typecheck(this)">Insurance</a>
      <a href="#"   data-role="button" id="button7" onclick="typecheck(this)">Others</a>
    </div>              
  <label id="exptype">Label:</label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this (remember case sensitive):

```
function typecheck(objButton)
{
switch(objButton.innerHTML){
case "Grocery": exptype.innerHTML= "grocery";
                break;
case "Medical": exptype.innerHTML= "medical";
                break;
case "Education": exptype.innerHTML= "education";
                break;
case "Entertainment": exptype.innerHTML= "entertainment";
                break;
case "Automobile": exptype.innerHTML= "automobile";
                break;
case "Insurance": exptype.innerHTML= "insurance";
                break;
default:  exptype.innerHTML= "others";
                break;     
}                                         
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer!! it actually makes it work but the answer is not as expected. it shows others for all the buttons

Comment: this is working in jsfiddle.net not in my worklight project. seems weird and is driving me nuts.

Comment: check firebug console for errors. this maight help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem lies with your passing in of `this` in `typecheck(this)`. Your switch case is checking strings against a DOM object. Instead I would pass in this.innerHTML like this `typecheck(this.innerHTML)`

Comment: Anything in your error console? Also remember to say 'var' before your variable declarations inside the function, otherwise the variables will be global.

Comment: no nothing in the error console. and i did use var before variables. i tried the approach given in the above answer but the answer always comes out to be **others**

Answer (score 0):

You had a couple of issues, but specifically you need to test the text, either innerHTML or innerText, instead of the object. Also, Javascript is case-sensitive. This fiddle works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/5VJ2H/

```
function typecheck(objButton) {
    exptype = document.getElementById("exptype");
    grocery = document.getElementById("button");
    medical = document.getElementById("button2");
    education = document.getElementById("button3");
    entertainment = document.getElementById("button4");
    automobile = document.getElementById("button5");
    insurance = document.getElementById("button6");
    others = document.getElementById("button7");

    switch (objButton.innerHTML.toLowerCase()){
    case "grocery":
      exptype.innerHTML = "grocery";
      break;
    case "medical":
      exptype.innerHTML = "medical";
      break;
    case "education":
      exptype.innerHTML = "education";
      break;
    case "entertainment":
      exptype.innerHTML = "entertainment";
      break;
    case "automobile":
      exptype.innerHTML = "automobile";
      break;
    case "insurance":
      exptype.innerHTML = "insurance";
      break;
    default:
      exptype.innerHTML = "others";
      break;
    }
}
```

Comment: it makes work 'others' as output no matter the button clicked